# Why can't ipdb be imported when using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, ipdb

I am not trying to *use* `ipdb` with multiprocessing, I had it imported before I started adding multiprocessing features and I couldn't figure out why the code wouldn't run. Here is a minimal example;

```
from ipdb import set_trace as st
import multiprocessing

def worker(instructions):
   return "good boi"

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
results = [pool.apply(worker, args=("woof", )) for _ in range(3)]
pool.close()
```

If you comment out the first line it runs, otherwise it prints a cryptic error message about failing to pickle worker. I don't need `ipdb`, but why does this happen?